# handling user sign up roles with RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was wondering what would be the most logical way of handling which type of user a user would sign up?

When a user registered their say:

`name, email, password`

They get redirected to another page asking which role they're interested in signing up:

`business or resident`

Should I just assign a new column in users table in their database? `string :role`? Or should I create a new table? And what gem would work best for handling something like this? Eventually I would want to output different view layouts depending on user's role

Thanks

Comment: I believe the best way for something like this would be to use CanCan - https://github.com/ryanb/cancan. I believe something that is regarding roles. This allows you to define roles in your `ability` class. From defining your roles. You could then add a `if-else` in your controller that would check what role the user is. Dependent on their role this would redirect them to the different pages.

Comment: will the role be always business/resident?

Comment: you can define your your own roles

Comment: @David I'll look into cancan.

Comment: @JSWorld Yes, because user can only be a business owner, or just a resident

Comment: @andrewliu take a look at my answer may give you some clarity on what you want to do. But do note my example takes in the assumption that potentially a user can have more than one role. However this can be changed by simply changing the relation between `Role` and `User` from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `belongs_to`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I stated the best gem for something like this would be CanCan because it allows you to alter your roles to how you want. With the ability to filter out particular actions for different roles. To go about this I suggest to do the following:

*1. Adding Roles*

```
rails g scaffold Role name:string
```

*2. HABTM relationship between roles and users*

```
rails generate migration UsersHaveAndBelongsToManyRoles
```

```
class UsersHaveAndBelongsToManyRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :role, :user
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

*3.Modify the Role model, so it looks like the following*

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

*4. Altering User model*

Add :role_ids to attr_accessible so that you can then add the following method to identify the role of a particular user.

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, 
  :remember_me, :role_ids

  def role?(role)
    !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end
end
```

*5. Seeding roles*

```
%w(Business Administrator Resident).each { |role| Role.create!(:name => role) }
```

The above is a literal array of the roles

So you could do something like this as an example:

```
b = User.create!(:email => "example@example.com",
                 :password => "pass",
                 :password_confirmation => "pass",
)
b.roles << Role.first
b.save
```

*6. Registration form*

Your registration form may look like the following this is an example:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>
           prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <% if @current_method == "new" %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% for role in Role.find(:all) %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", 
           role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
      <%= role.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The above form will allow the user to select their role.

*6. Migrate your database*
   `rake db:migrate`

*7. Defining permissions using CanCan*

Generate the `ability` class using - rails g cancan:ability

**Ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user

    if user.role? :administrator

      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, User

    elsif user.role? :business
      can [:create, :new], Business
      can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id 

    else user.role? :resident 
     can [:show, :update], User, :id => user.id

    end
  end
end
```

As you stated you want to show different parts of a page to different users. So you may have on a particular view the following `if-else`

**Example View**

```
  <% if current_user.role? business %> 

     #Show stuff visible to business user

   <% else current_user.role? resident %> 

      #Show stuff visible to resident user

 <% end %>
```

Hopefully this gives some clarity on what you want to do

Filter example:

```
 def admin_business_user
    redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => 
    'You must be an admin to do that!' 
          unless current_user.role? :administrator || :business 
  end
```

Comment: Thanks David! This is great help!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out, how come its not displaying the checkbox for the roles? Do I have to add the role names in my database first?

Comment: @andrewliu see the revisions to step 2 and step 5. Step 2 I have added what your migration should look like. Step 5 I have added the literal array.

Comment: @andrewliu You know we can take this even further if we wanted. Once you have defined your roles it gets nicer. You could write a method in your application controllers that filter out actions in the controller. I will provide an example.

Comment: excellent answer! quick question, I'm trying to figure out where to put the `seeding` code you're referring to? For some reason its not displaying the options in my registration form. sorry for the dumb questions, i'm still n00b!

Comment: For step 5 I put the `seeded` code in `db/seeds.rb`. Did you add the `Roles` and `UsersHaveAndBelongsToManyRoles`

Comment: I created it, added it to db/seeds. now I'm getting undefined method roles from `role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>`?

Comment: Did you `rake db:migrate` and everything worked? I believe this should work. Usually this is the case whereby the roles have not been defined in the `user.rb` class. Please also take a look at the following: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model. My example is somewhat similar to his.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only going to have 2 roles then it is probably easiest to add a column to your users model.

```
rails generate migration add_business_to_users business:boolean
```

Then in the migration add a default to this column like

```
class AddBusinessToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :business, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Once you have migrated this to your database you have everything you need for 2 roles. For example you can always use

```
user.business? #This will be true for a user that is a business and false for resident
```

What you are effectively assuming is that every user that is not a business is a resident.

If you are going to have more roles then it makes sense to have a separate roles model or use a gem like cancan.